# Regex: remove non-alphanumeric chars, multiple whitespaces and trim() all together

Tags: php, regex

I have a $text to strip off all non-alphanumeric chars, replace multiple white spaces and newline by single space and eliminate beginning and ending space.

This is my solution so far.

```
$text = '
some-    text!! 

for testing?
'; // $text to format

//strip off all non-alphanumeric chars
$text = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $text);

//Replace multiple white spaces by single space 
$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);

//eliminate beginning and ending space
$finalText = trim($text);
/* result: $finalText ="some text for testing";
without non-alphanumeric chars, newline, extra spaces and trim()med */
```

Is it possible to combine/achieve all these in one regular expression? as I would get the desired result in one line as below

```
$finalText = preg_replace(some_reg_expression, $replaceby, $text);
```

thanks

Edit: clarified with a test string

Comment: @IgorChubin apparently you can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. That is very easy.

The re will look like:

```
((?<= )\s*)|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]|(\s*$)|(^\s*)
```

I have no PHP at hand, I have used Perl (just to test the re and show that it works) (you can play with my code [here](http://ideone.com/epDJW)):

```
$ cat test.txt 
         a       b       c    d
a b c e f g             fff  f

$ cat 1.pl 
while(<>) {
    s/((?<= )\s*)|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]|(\s*$)|(^\s*)//g;
    print $_,"\n";
}

$ cat test.txt | perl 1.pl 
a b c d
a b c e f g fff f
```

For PHP it will be the same.

What does the RE?

```
((?<= )\s*)       # all spaces that have at least one space before them
|
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]    # all non-alphanumeric characters
|
(\s*$)            # all spaces at the end of string
|
(^\s*)            # all spaces at the beginning of string
```

The only tricky part here is `((?<= )\s*)`, *lookbehind assertion*. You remove spaces if and only if the substring of spaces has a space before.

When you want to know how lookahead/lookbehind assertions work, please take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

**Update from the discussion**:

What happens when `$text ='some ? ! ? text';`? 
Then the resulting string contains multiple spaces between "some" and "text".

It is not so easy to solve the problem, because one need positive lookbehind assertions with variable length, and that is not possible at the moment. One cannot simple check spaces because it can happen so that it is not a space but non-alphanumerich character and it will be removed anyway (for example: in `" !"` the `"!"` sign will be removed but RE knows nothing about; one need something like `(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]* )\s*` but that unfortunately will not work because PCRE does not support lookbehind variable length assertions.

Comment: Pretty neat, especially the lookbehind assertion.

Comment: Works as requested, but not as in the example code.
Multiple whitespace inbetween text is replaced by any random whitespace character of that matched set, not by a space character as in the example. Being able to do so would require being able to replace one character by another while also replacing other characters by nothing. I don't think PCRE regex can do both of these at the same time.
Also, the lookbehind explicitely requires a space, not any whitespace character, but this can be easily fixed.

Comment: thanks Igor Chubin. I've edited my question and added a test string to clarify. It seems `((?<= )\s*)|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]|(\s*$)|(^\s*)` won't do this all these.

Comment: May be I don't understand what you want to get, but as far as I understand, all works perfect. Please take a look at: http://ideone.com/epDJW

Comment: @Martijn: You are right, the only point that I would like to correct: multiple whitespaces is replaced with the _first_ space from the set (you have said "by any random whitespace character")

Comment: thanks again  Igor Chubin for ur great effort.
In that example it's ok. but how about this `$text ='some ? ! ? text';` the resulting string contains multiple spaces between "some" and "text"

Comment: Igor Chubin, please look at here [http://ideone.com/85vtP](http://ideone.com/85vtP)

Comment: @user1437295: I fear that is impossible. Because you need positive lookbehind assertions with variable length, and that is not possible at the moment. You cannot simple check spaces because it can happen so that it is not a space but non-alphanumerich character and it will be removed anyway (for example: in " !" the "!" sign will be removed but RE knows nothing about; yut need something like `(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]* )\s*` but that unfortunately will not work because PCRE does not support lookbehind variable length assertions.

Comment: @Igor Chubin: thanks for great effort to help. As it's not possible, I'm satisfied with the solution that I have already. please update ur answer with this last conclusion so that I can make it answered.

Comment: @user1437295: I added the last conclusion to the answer as you wished. Thank you for the approval and for the nice question!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can achieve that with one regex. You would basically need to stick in an `if else` condition, which it is not possible through Regular Expressions alone.

You would basically need one regex to remove non-alphanumeric digits and another one to collapse the spaces, which is basically what you are already doing.

Comment: thanks for expert opinion. after several efforts to help, [Igor Chubin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114307/regex-remove-non-alphanumeric-chars-multiple-whitespaces-and-trim-all-togeth#comment14565118_11114613) also reached in the same conclusion. May be I think my question was not clear enough at first.

Answer (score 1):

Check this if this is what you are looking for ---

```
$patterns = array ('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/','/\s+/');
$replace = array ("", ' ');
trim( preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $text) );
```

MAy be it may need some modification, just let me know if this is something what you want to do??

Comment: @AdnanShammout thx man ...at least you are more active with the  response than the questionnaire

Answer (score 0):

For your own sanity, you will want to keep regular expressions that you can still understand and edit later on :)

```
$text = preg_replace(array(
    "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", // remove all non-space, non-alphanumeric characters
    '/\s{2,}/', // replace multiple white space occurrences with single 
), array(
    '', 
    ' ',
), trim($originalText));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text =~ s/([^a-zA-Z0-9\s].*?)//g;
```

Doesn't have to be any harder than this.